# Unable to get null values for the count per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am not sure what I am doing to get this wrong. I am trying to get the count of usertb.id per each month. I want the 0s to be displayed if the count is null. I am using a left outer join with a month table that consists just the id of the month and name of the month. Please help. I am using SQL SERVER 2008

```
SELECT 
     monthTB.name
     ,subTB.name
     ,COUNT(userTB.ID)
FROM TDP_NetOps.dbo.sub_activity AS subTB
     ,TDP_NetOps.dbo.month AS monthTB
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TDP_NetOps.dbo.user_sub_activity AS userTB ON monthTB.ID = DATEPART(month, userTB.date_of_activity)
WHERE 
     subTB.sub_activity_id = userTB.sub_activity_id
     AND userTB.emp_id = 'xxxx'
GROUP BY 
       monthTB.name
       ,monthTB.ID
       ,subTB.name
ORDER BY 
       monthTB.ID ASC
       ,subTB.name ASC
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are a few things wrong with your query:

Firstly, do not use implicit `JOIN` syntax(comma separated) , use the proper syntax of join.

Secondly, if you do use them, don't ever mix them together with the explicit syntax, it will always lead to mistakes.

And lastly, conditions on the right table of a left join should be inside the `ON` clause, when specified in the where, the join turns into an inner join. :

```
SELECT monthTB.name
     , subTB.name
     , COUNT(userTB.ID)
FROM TDP_NetOps.dbo.sub_activity AS subTB
CROSS JOIN TDP_NetOps.dbo.month AS monthTB
LEFT OUTER JOIN TDP_NetOps.dbo.user_sub_activity AS userTB 
ON (monthTB.ID = DATEPART(month, userTB.date_of_activity)
    AND subTB.sub_activity_id = userTB.sub_activity_id
    AND userTB.emp_id = 'xxxx')
GROUP BY monthTB.name
       , monthTB.ID
       , subTB.name
ORDER BY monthTB.ID ASC
       , subTB.name ASC
```

Comment: Thank you very much sagi. I am fairly new to sql, and I am still trying to learn. Thank you for the pointers, I will be looking at what you have said.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause is undoing the `LEFT JOIN`.  I think this is the logic that you want:

```
SELECT monthTB.name, subTB.name
       COUNT(userTB.ID)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT subTB.sub_activity_id
      FROM TDP_NetOps.dbo.sub_activity subTB
      WHERE subTB.emp_id = 'xxxx'
     ) subTB CROSS JOIN
     TDP_NetOps.dbo.month AS monthTB LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TDP_NetOps.dbo.user_sub_activity userTB
     ON monthTB.ID = DATEPART(month, userTB.date_of_activity) AND
        subTB.sub_activity_id = userTB.sub_activity_id AND
        subTB.emp_id = 'xxxx'
GROUP BY monthTB.name, monthTB.ID, subTB.name
ORDER BY monthTB.ID ASC, subTB.name ASC;
```

I'm not sure if the second filter on `emp_id` is really needed.  That depends on what the data looks like.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT monthTB.name
     , subTB.name
     , COALESCE(COUNT(userTB.ID),0)
FROM TDP_NetOps.dbo.sub_activity AS subTB
   , TDP_NetOps.dbo.month AS monthTB
LEFT OUTER JOIN TDP_NetOps.dbo.user_sub_activity AS userTB ON monthTB.ID = DATEPART(month, userTB.date_of_activity)
WHERE subTB.sub_activity_id = userTB.sub_activity_id
    AND userTB.emp_id = 'xxxx'
GROUP BY monthTB.name
       , monthTB.ID
       , subTB.name
ORDER BY monthTB.ID ASC
       , subTB.name ASC
```

Comment: Will still do the same!

Comment: it does not work. it does not display the values that are null

Comment: Can you provide sample data in temp tables. It'd be easy to test.